# Помощь с Node Js ( Библиотека node-vk-bot-api )?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

Пишу чат бота,как можно сделать так,что бы бот отвечал на непонятные сообщения?(Тобиш которых нет в коде)?

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.command(/(.|\n)*?/, async (ctx) => ... );
```

Добавь эту строку в самый конец, после всех остальных bot.command. Первым аргументом передано регулярное выражение, которое срабатывает на любую строку. В теории, эта команда должна срабатывать, когда все остальные не сработали.
А вообще рекомендую попробовать библиотеку vk-io, она более дружелюбна к новичкам.